# SharePoint 2016 Login Popup recurring

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem

i installed a SharePoint 2016 server.
Now i have a domain and want to access sharepoint over this domain.
The domain is `mysupersharepoint2016.domain`

I created a new web application with this domain. When i call the domain from the sharepoint server in edge the login prompt is recurring infinitely. But when i call the domain from a different pc i can login like a charm.
Now i don't unterstand why it's working from remote but not from local?

Can you give my an advice why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to disable Loopback Check for SharePoint with the command:

```
New-ItemProperty HKLM:\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa -Name “DisableLoopbackCheck” -value “1” -PropertyType dword
```

Reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37664.sharepoint-2013-disable-loopback-check.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect <3

Comment: Glad that hleps you, you could accept my answer :-)